# How to create Nested Routing in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

[image]

I created this page. The top Navbar is working perfectly as Excepted.

Navlink :-

```
...
<NavLink to="/about" id="menu" className="nav-link">About</NavLink>
...
```

Routing :-

```
<Routes>
       ...
       <Route path="/about" element={<About/>} />
       ...
</Routes>
```

I want the below Navbar with **Profile & Timeline** to render component below that.

I've written code for below Navbar in **About Component** as follows :-

Navlink :-

```
<NavLink to="/about/profile" id="menu" className="nav-link">Profile</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/about/timeline" id="menu" className="nav-link">Timeline</NavLink>
```

Routing :-

```
<Routes>
      <Route path="/about/profile" element={<Profile />}/>
      ...
</Routes>
```

But it render blank component. I want to render the desired component inside About Component

Comment: I don't see any nested routes. Is `<Route path="/about/profile" element={<Profile />} />` a sibling route? Can you post a more complete [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, With the help of `<Outlet/>` component of **react-router-dom** it solved the problem

```
<Route path="/about" element={<About/>}>
    <Route index element={<Profile/>} />
    <Route path="/about/profile" element={<Profile/>} />
    <Route path="/about/timeline" element={<Timeline/>} />
</Route>
```

And inside the **About Component** we have to put `<Outlet/>` where we want to render the Child Component.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this post...

[React nested routes](https://dev.to/junko911/how-to-implement-nested-routes-with-react-router-59oe#:%7E:text=React%20Router%20uses%20nested%20routes%20to%20render%20more,we%20could%20set%20routes%20for%20details%20pages%20dynamically.)